# Is there such a datagrid / calender control or similar in .net or any hardcode way to do it?

Tags: .net, datagridview, calendar

So i have a database and i store these values:

```
Name : John
Date : 20 September 2012
Status : T
```

I want to have a data grid or table or calender control that shows data like below : 
[image]

It shows the dates on top as columns from 1 to 31 and below the data it shows the corresponding day that is Monday , tuesday and so on and finally it shows the name and status appropriate to each date.

I am not sure if there is a control or hardcode way of doing it. I don't mind buying a third party control if it exists and it makes it easier to show data in the above format.

Using Vb.net and framework 3.5.